# Source control terminology?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I store visual studio code using my online developer account at `https://mycode.visualstudio.com/`, using `Team Foundation Version Control` (not Git).

When it comes to accurate wording for documentation and folder structures, how should I best refer to this repositry?
"**TFS**", "**VSTS**", "**TFVC**", "**VSTS-TFVC**", etc ?

Which correctly describes the type of source control and the location of the repository I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> TFVC repository hosted in VSTS.

VSTS is a cloud platform - a set of services. It can host repositories of two types: Git and TFVC. You can host multiple repositories of each kind in any team project of your VSTS account.

Here is a good article about both source control systems: [Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=vsts).

Comment: Thanks.  So avoid using "TFS" to refer to this?

Comment: Right, TFS stands for Team Foundation Server - the on-prem version of what VSTS offers as a service. Note that VSTS is updated every 3 weeks, as far as I know, while TFS has its own release cadence and you should upgrade it manually.